# Android ndk ncurses

Tags: android-ndk, ncurses, ndk-build

I'm trying to compile ncurses for android and build the ncurses static library. However I cannot understand how to go about.Anyone with any idea how to go about it using ndk-build?

Comment: You need an Android.mk, there are some older ones on Github https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_libncurses